# Очередь в питоне

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, очередь

Ищу библиотеку или код который создает очередь.Т.е. есть функция которая иногда вызывается и она долна ввести новое значение в конец очереди.И есть другая функция которая выполняет задания по вызову надо читать старое (которое первым пришел – первым обслужен) и удаляет ео из очереди, и так далее пока очередь не выполнится

```
def x():
 f(id)#какая то функция которая добавляет в очередь значение 
 y()

def y():
 count = f2()#функция которая выводит длину очереди
 for i in range(count)
  id - f3()#функция которая выводит значение из списка и удаляет его и передвигает список вперед(ну типа такого)
  #какой то код
```

Что то типа такого

Comment: [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

Comment: Для многопоточности так и называется [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from queue import SimpleQueue  # можно просто Queue - методов больше

def to_queue(a, my_queue):
    my_queue.put(a)

def from_queue(my_queue):
    while not my_queue.empty():
        b = my_queue.get()

my_queue = SimpleQueue()
```

`SimpleQueue` - очередь с минимально необходимым набором методов. Дальше можно уже делать с этими данными, что у Вас в алгоритме предусмотрено.